# Avoid hang when writing to named pipe which disappears and comes back

Tags: python

I have a program which dumps information into a named pipe like this:

```
cmd=open(destination,'w')
cmd.write(data)
cmd.close()
```

This works pretty well until the pipe (destination) disappears while my program is writing to it. The problem is that it keeps hanging on the write part(?)
I was expecting some exception to happen, but that's not the case.
How can I avoid this situation?

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: What OS are we talking about?

Comment: That's linux.  Indeed important to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the process reading from the pipe is not reading as fast as your writing, your script will block when it tries to write to the pipe.  From the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_(Unix)):

> "If the queue buffer fills up, the
>   sending program is suspended (blocked)
>   until the receiving program has had a
>   chance to read some data and make room
>   in the buffer. In Linux, the size of
>   the buffer is 65536 bytes."

Luckly you have a few options:

- The signal module will allow you to set an alarm to break out of the write call.  After the prescribed amount of time, a SIGALRM signal will be sent to your process, if your handler for the signal raises an exception, it will break you out of the write.
- With threading, you can spawn a new thread to handle the writing, killing it if it blocks for too long.
- You can also use the fnctl module to make the pipe nonblocking (meaning the call will not wait, it will fail immediately if the pipe is full): [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-stream-in-python).
- Finally, you can use the select module to check if the pipe is ready for writing before attempting your write, just be careful, the check-write action is not idempotent (e.g. the pipe could fill up between the check and write).

Comment: I will have a look into the 3rd option and if that doesn't work out, I think the second option would fit my purpose then.  Signal is not an option as this writing happens in a thread already. The Fourth option sounds tricky as i'm possibly not the only process writing to that pipe.

Comment: `select` is easy to use, but I believe that, in this case, it may not be perfectly adequate as the pipe may disappear between the `select()` call and the `write()` call.

Comment: Yea Pedro, that's the problem.  The OS could do a context switch right after the check, fill up the pipe, and switch back to your write (which will now fail).

Comment: Ops. It seems you have already mentioned that in your response. I guess I should not post just before going to bed. Sorry. :)

Comment: I chose to do the writing in a dedicated thread and use a join with timeout on the thread object, which looks like it's doing the job.
But now the problem is a bit, how to kill the thread? As killing threads appears to be not good practice, ... but in my case it's pretty clear.  I do "del object" to kill the thread, ... I hope this is sufficient.

Comment: Have you tried the `exit()` method? http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.exit

Answer (score 0):

I think that the signal module can help you. Check this example:

http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#example

(The example solves an possibly non-finishing `open()` call, but can be trivially modified to do the same thing to your `cmd.write()` call.)

Comment: It indeed crossed my mind and it would be a way out, but it's currently not an option, because the writing happens in a blocking thread and apparently it's not possible to use signals in threads but only in the main() ... It would require quite some redesign for me the implement this.

Comment: What about receiving the signal in the main thread and then calling `thread.exit()`?

Comment: From what i have read is that signalling & threading should be avoided.  Anyhow, I have decided to make another thread which handles the actual writing within the thread which makes the decision to write.  I'm sure there are other ways too, but it works.